# What library can I use for working with VoIP streams in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, voip

I want to write a VoIP program using C#, in which I want to encode/decode outgoing and incoming streams myself. I will appreciate, if you can tell me, what library I can use for it and where can I can find that library.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [NSpeex](http://nspeex.codeplex.com/) for a fully managed codec implementation.

[NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com) will let you use any ACM codecs on your system, so you can use G.711 a-law and mu-law, ADPCM, GSM 6.10, G.723.1, TrueSpeech or WMA, which come with Windows as standard. It also has managed a-law and mu-law encode/decode.

Answer (score 0):

3rd party VoIP lib mostly not free.

VoIP stream has many encode/decode standard such as G.729, G.711. 
i have bought this [SIP VoIP SDK](http://www.abtollc.com/products/voip-solutions/voip-sip-sdk/) from Abto LLC

this library provide most standard VoIP codecs and essential methods to establish connection via SIP protocal.